# decode urlencoded string, or apache rejects url due to '/' in params

Tags: python, apache, url-encoding

I am developing Mobile application which uses python in its server
side(apache server) , I send some parameters to the server,and am
sending these parameter after encoding two times ,(other wise apache
gives 400 error due to a '/' in the encoded parameter). I came to
this solution after reading the [article](http://www.jampmark.com/web-scripting/5-solutions-to-url-encoded-slashes-problem-in-apache.html)

And my server in turn sends a request to another server using the same parameter,
So i want to decode it in to its previous form.

Is there any way in python to decode the encoded parameters in python?

Or whether I move to the other solutions described in the above article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `unquote()` from [urllib.parse](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.parse.unquote) (python 3.x) or [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#utility-functions) (python 2.x)

Comment: But if I encode a string with spaces and then decode it ,the deoded string not equal to the orginal one,it has an extra '+' symbol in place of spaces.

Comment: Then _something_ (apache?) is doing extra work with the url because `unquote(quote('a b c d'))` returns 'a b c d'

Comment: python is expecting %20 as the space character encoding, although '+' is also valid.

Comment: maybe you should use unquote_plus